# RegEx: Matching n-char long sequence of repeating character

Tags: java, regex

I want to split of a text string that might look like this:

`(((Hello!` --> `(((` and `Hello!`

or
`########No?` --> `########` and `No?`

At the beginning I have n-times the same special character, but I want to match the longest possible sequence.

What I have at the moment is this regex:
`([^a-zA-Z0-9])\\1+([a-zA-Z].*)`

This one would return for the first example 
`(` (only 1 time) and `Hello!`

and for the second
`#` and `No!`

How do I tell regEx I want the maximal long repetition of the matching character?

I am using RegEx as part of a Java program in case this matters.

Comment: `([^a-zA-Z0-9])\1+` → `(([^a-zA-Z0-9])\2+)` and use groups 1 and 3.

Comment: Just a demo on regex101 for the regex proposed by @Biffen : https://regex101.com/r/mD9vW7/1

Comment: Thank you Biffen your solution works!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following solution with 2 regexps: `(?s)(\\W)\\1+\\w.*` for checking if the string contains same repeating non-word symbols at the start, and if yes, split with a mere `(?<=\\W)(?=\\w)` pattern (between non-word and a word character), else, just return a list containing the whole string (as if not split):

```
String ptrn = "(?<=\\W)(?=\\w)";
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("(((Hello!", "########No?", "$%^&^Hello!");
for (String str : strs) {
    if (str.matches("(?s)(\\W)\\1+\\w.*")) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(ptrn)));
    }else { System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str)); }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/sIZnKM)

Result:

```
[(((, Hello!]
[########, No?]
[$%^&^Hello!]
```

Also, your original regex can be modified to fit the requirement like this:

```
String ptrn = "(?s)((\\W)\\2+)(\\w.*)";
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("(((Hello!", "########No?", "$%^&^Hello!");
for (String str : strs) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ptrn);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(m.group(1), m.group(3)));
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str)); 
    }
}
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/3t1nhr)

That regex matches:

- `(?s)` - DOTALL inline modifier (if the string has newline characters, `.*` will also match them).
- `((\\W)\\2+)` - Capture group 1 matching and *capturing* into Group 2 a non-word character followed by the same character (since a backreference `\2` is used) 1 or more times.
- `(\\w.*)` - matches and captures into Group 3 a word character and then one or more characters.